# How to display new lines in div element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element that I add text to with JavaScript. I want new text added to be on a new line. I have tried two methods, both seem to work when looking at the text in the developer window, but the new lines get ignored on the actual page. Here are the two methods I've tried:

```
targetEl.textContent += "\n" + sourceIdEl.textContent;

targetEl.textContent += document.writeln(sourceIdEl.textContent);
```

Both seem to work in the dev window:

[image: Dev Window]
But the lines get ignored on the actual page:

[image: Page Display]

Here is the CSS applied to the div element:

```css
.board-list {
    background-color: rgb(235, 236, 240);
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    min-height: 100px;
    height: max-content;
    padding:6px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can also use CSS `white-space` also if you do not want to insert br tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line breaks in HTML are just like ordinary white-space.

Try

```
targetEl.innerHTML += "<br>" + sourceIdEl.textContent
```

```js
"use strict";

;(function(d) {
  var items = [
    '1640DF9447 - Petersen Group - Temp Fence',
    '1710DF0204 - MNDOT Detroit Lakes',
    '1710DF5250 - Lenthe, Dirk - Fabricate And Install Fence',
    "1810DF1601 - ND Petroleum Equipment-6' Chainlink Fence Install Hallok MN",
    '1820DF1012 - Fort Abraham Lincoln Foundation Heritage River Temp Fence',
  ]
  var addListItem = function() {
    var bl = d.getElementById('board-list')
    bl.innerHTML += items.shift() + "<br>"
  }
  d.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('#add-board-list-item')) {
      addListItem()
    }
  })
}(document));
```

```css
.board-list {
    background-color: rgb(235, 236, 240);
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    min-height: 100px;
    height: max-content;
    padding:6px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-board-list-item">Add Item</button>
<div class="board-list" id="board-list"></div>
```

or use

```
  white-space: pre-line;
```

```js
"use strict";

;(function(d) {
  var items = [
    '1640DF9447 - Petersen Group - Temp Fence',
    '1710DF0204 - MNDOT Detroit Lakes',
    '1710DF5250 - Lenthe, Dirk - Fabricate And Install Fence',
    "1810DF1601 - ND Petroleum Equipment-6' Chainlink Fence Install Hallok MN",
    '1820DF1012 - Fort Abraham Lincoln Foundation Heritage River Temp Fence',
  ]
  var addListItem = function() {
    var bl = d.getElementById('board-list')
    bl.textContent += items.shift() + "\n"
  }
  d.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.closest('#add-board-list-item')) {
      addListItem()
    }
  })
}(document));
```

```css
.board-list {
    background-color: rgb(235, 236, 240);
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    min-height: 100px;
    height: max-content;
    padding:6px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    white-space: pre-line
}
```

```html
<button id="add-board-list-item">Add Item</button>
<div class="board-list" id="board-list"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working so far. Quick question, I store this text content in an SQL Server table as a varchar. Will `<br>` tags get stored and loaded correctly if I set the field to targetEl.innerHTML?

Comment: I don't know anything about how you store them, so I cannot make any suggestion about that

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\n` to `<br>`

```js
const lineBreakText = `
  some 
  text
  with
  line
  breaks
`;

const element = document.querySelector('#lineBreakText');

element.innerHTML = lineBreakText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

```html
<div id="lineBreakText"></div>
```